# Get the sum value of selected check boxes on check box click with jquery after ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to get the sum value of selected check boxes on check box click with jquery  after ajax response.

```
$('.check:checked').each(function() {   });
```

The above jQuery function works if I call the check box when the page loading
but I have to call this function after an AJAX response it's not working.

So I have tried with below one but no idea to get the sum of the selected check boxes value

```
$('body').on('click', '.check', function(){ }
```

jQuery function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('body').on('click', '.check', function(){
            var tot  = 5;
            $('.check:checked').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());                      
                tot += $(this).val();
            });
            console.log(tot);
        }); 
$('#payType').change(function(){
    var pType = $(this).val();
    var y = $('[name = "year"]').val();
    clearRuntimeFunctions();                        

    $('#payType').val(pType);
    if(pType != "dntSntReqst"){                     
        $('#ajax_img_lod').show();          

        $.ajax({            
            url: 'AJAX_Requst/getOtherPaymt.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'pYear': y,
                'payType': pType,                   
            },
            success: function( data ){
                $('#ajax_img_lod').hide();                                      
                $('#ajax_response').html(data);


            }
        });
    }
});
    });
</script>
```

This an AJAX response page

```
<?php
    <table class="table table-message" style="margin: 10px 25px;max-width: 350px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="heading">                    
                <td class="cell-title"> Year </td>
                <td class="cell-title"> Month </td>
                <td class="cell-title"><div align="right"> Amount  </div></td> 
                <td class="cell-title"><div align="right"> Balance</div> </td> 
                <td class="" width="2%"><div align="right"></div></td>
            </tr>

            foreach($monthEnd_Arry as $m)
            {
                $sql_cls = mysql_query("SELECT book FROM cls_room_tb WHERE cls_brnch_id='$br_id' AND start_date <= '$m'");
                $noCls = mysql_num_rows($sql_cls);
                if ($noCls > 0) {
                    if ($noCls <= 4) {
                        $centFee = $noCls * 1000;   
                    }
                    else {
                        $centFee = 4 * 1000;                    
                        $centFee += ($noCls - 4) * 500;                     
                    }

                    $sql_paid = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM other_payments WHERE br_id='$br_id' AND pay_type='$payType' AND 
                    pYear = '$pYear' AND pMonth='". substr($m , 5, 2)."'");
                    $res_paid = mysql_fetch_row($sql_paid);
                    $paidAmount = $res_paid[0];
                    $amount =  $centFee  ;

                    echo '<tr class="unread">  
                        <td class="cell-title" >'.$pYear.'</td>
                        <td class="cell-title" >'.month_crt( substr($m , 5, 2)).' - '.$noCls.' </td>
                        <td class="cell-title" >
                                <div align="right"> '.numFormt($amount).'</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell-title" ><div align="right">'.numFormt( $amount - $paidAmount ).'</div></td>
                        <td class="cell-title" >
                            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="checkPay[]" value="'.numFormt( $amount - $paidAmount ).'" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>'; 
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: `but I have to call this function after an AJAX response it's not working` How that?Please provide relevant code regarding ajax request too

Comment: the above php is the response. it's working fine

Comment: I'm not talking about server side code but client side one used to call it. You need to sum up using relevant ajax callback.

Comment: i have update the ajax request too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum it up inside ajax success callback, e.g:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'AJAX_Requst/getOtherPaymt.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'pYear': y,
            'payType': pType,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#ajax_img_lod').hide();
        $('#ajax_response').html(data);
        // find(':checked') for checked ones 
        // even none seems checked regarding your servser side script
        // so maybe use `.find('.check')` instead but that's not clear what you are expecting here???
        var sum = $('#ajax_response').find(':checked').map(function () {
            return +this.value
        }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        });
        // do whatever you want with `sum`
        console.log(sum);
    }
});
```

Or maybe you want to call it on:

```
$(document).on('change', '.check', function () {
    var sum = $('.check').filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return +this.value
    }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }/* to start with default value != 0 as '5' in your posted code*/, 5);
    // do whatever you want with `sum`
    console.log(sum);
}
```

In fact, i'm not sure to understand what is your expected behaviour. How/when do you wish to sum up checked checkboxes values?!

Comment: once the ajax response contend loaded then only the user have to select multiple check boxes then a text box going to show the sum of the selected check boxes amount

Comment: @NSK Then i think the second solution is what you are looking for. EDIT: but wait, this should be the same as what you already have: `$('body').on('click', '.check', function(){...});` so i'm quite confused...?! Indeed i still don't understand expected behaviour

Comment: i think  on('click')  is more  suitable  than .on('change').. but both are working fine

Comment: @NSK No in fact `change` would be more suitable especially regarding older browsers which don't update checked state until click event as reached document level (even here we are delegating it at dociment level). BTW, sementically speaking, this is more correct to use `change` too.BUT as jQuery as normalized this behaviour, you can use `click`, it will work just fine. From jQuery source: `// For checkbox, fire native event so checked state will be right
   `if ( jQuery.nodeName( this, "input" ) && this.type === "checkbox" && this.click ) {
     this.click();
     return false;
    }`